# Load video URL from any website to ANDROID app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video, load

Suppose I have video url from any website

(For example: https://1080.opstream4.com/share/c40c01024a2299498ce379d3253daec4)

I want load url and play video in my android app.

Can anyone show me steps to resolve this problem?